# Import new functions from file in C at runtime

Tags: c, linux, gcc

Is there any way to import a file of functions at runtime in C? Meaning that from user input (or maybe as compiled programs are added to a directory), the main function could call functions in these using trampolines?

For example, a directory would contain the executable `x`, with the functions it has available in `x.txt` or similar. Then, the main program would take user input to load the code in `x`, and to select a function in `x.txt`, such that new functions could be added without stopping the main program, in a manner similar to kernel modules. Ideally, these modules could also be unloaded during runtime.

I've considered using `exec` and threads, but would like something less vulnerable to attacks, and with less overhead. GCC- and Linux-exclusive features are an option, since portability to other operating systems is not a priority.

Comment: [dlopen](https://linux.die.net/man/3/dlopen)

Comment: Dynamically loading and execute arbitrary functions from arbitrary executable or shared libraries is *always* going to be vulnerable and considered security holes.

Comment: You can use fabrice bellard's tcc library to compile code into into memory if you really want to.  That having been said, loading code into your own process is literally the most vulnerable, least secure thing you can do.  If you have compiled elf shared object (.so) files, you can also open and inspect them with dlopen and dlsym (and call functions from pointers returned by dlsym).  You could compile these with libtcc, tcc itself or any other compiler.

Comment: Thanks @StoryTeller, I think this will work perfectly.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude And yet it can be incredibly useful, for example if you want to have plugins written in C, rather than putting a scripting engine into your program.

Comment: @KennethB.Jensen: There is no need to use a separate text file to describe the functions. In fact, that can easily break (just consider someone accidentally editing the text file, or installing a newer binary without updating the text file). Instead, use a structure to describe each exported function. I've posted several example approaches as answers, for example [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36803328/c-plugin-system-dlopen-fails) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18797777/how-to-use-dlsym-reliably-when-you-have-duplicated-symbols), that might be useful for you.